# Get count within ArcGIS report

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, reports

I have a file gdb feature class which contains cropland fields, and within the table are data fields for Landowner, Acres, and many other items.  I have a report based on the table which has no data within the detail section, but is grouped on the Landowner.  I have the summation of the Acres for each Landowner within the Landowner group footer , and a grand total of the Acres in the report footer.

What I would like is also a count of the Landowners within the report footer. (This would also be a count of the times the group footer was generated.)

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your question would be clearer if you included pictures of your input table(s) and desired report that are kept as simple as possible and show what you already have and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  a Textbox (Landowner) to the ReportFooter and set its Summary parameters like this:

[image]

In the image, DCount, stands for distinct count.